# R/data.table: optimize "recursive" groupby

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, large-data

I'm working with a large data.table (1e6-10e6 rows, 10's of columns) with genomic data. I want reduce the data by reducing groups into single rows. This reduction depends on multiple columns, but in consecutive steps. Example data is like:

```
dt.tmp <- data.table(str1=paste0("A",sample(1:100, 2000, replace=TRUE)),
                     str2=paste0("B",sample(1:5, 2000, replace=TRUE)),
                     c1=sample(1:3,2000, replace=T), 
                     c2=sample(1:3,2000,replace=T),
                     d1=sample(1:2,2000,replace=T),
                     d2=sample(1:2,2000,replace=TRUE))
```

For this data I want to reduce on the *str1* column, using the following steps:

- Within group defined by *str1* create groups based on *str2* and select the largest group(s)
- In resulting group(s) select group(s) with max (c1+c2)
- In resulting group(s) select group(s) with max (d1+d2)
- In resulting group(s) select a random row

I've tried various combinations of operating on .SD, like:

```
dt.tmp[,':='(c=c1+c2, d=d1+d2,rnd=sample.int(.N))
    ][,':='(n=.N),by=.(str1,str2)
    ][,.SD[n==max(n), 
           .SD[c==max(c), 
               .SD[d==max(d), 
                   .SD[rnd==max(rnd)], by=d], 
                   by=c], 
               by=n],
            by=str1];
```

My final attempt attempts to minimize using .SD:

```
dt.tmp[,':='(c=c1+c2, d=d1+d2, rnd=sample.int(.N))
     ][,':='(n=.N,cmaxidx=(c==max(c))),by=.(str1,str2)
     ][,':='(nmaxidx=(n==max(n))),by=str1
     ][,':='(dmaxidx=(d==max(d))),by=.(str1,str2,c)
     ][,.SD[dmaxidx&cmaxidx&nmaxidx
     ][rnd==max(rnd)], by=str1
     ][,':='(c=NULL,d=NULL,nmaxidx=NULL,cmaxidx=NULL,dmaxidx=NULL,n=NULL,rnd=NULL)][,.SD]
```

(where the latter operations are merely to clean up and print)
I'm not at all "in to" data.table. Are there obvious optimizations I can apply to above problem/code to reduce execution time (currently I need 200-300 or so CPU hours, boiling down to  14 or so clock hours on our server using max 24 cores).
The real data looks like:

```
Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':  50259993 obs. of  26 variables:
 $ BC         : chr  "AAAAAAAAAAAACAAGGTCG" "AAAAAAAAAAAACTACCGTG" "AAAAAAAAAAAAGCACTGAG" "AAAAAAAAAAAAGCACTGAG" ...
 $ chrom      : chr  "chr2L" "chr2R" "chr2R" "chr2R" ...
 $ start      : int  22371281 12477441 8323580 8323580 17304870 31837917 24897443 22469324 22469324 18294732 ...
 $ end        : int  22371463 12477734 8323924 8323924 17305040 31838183 24897665 22469723 22469723 18295044 ...
 $ strand     : chr  "+" "+" "-" "-" ...
 $ MAPQ1      : int  1 40 42 42 42 42 24 1 1 42 ...
 $ MAPQ2      : int  1 40 42 42 42 42 24 1 1 42 ...
 $ AS1        : int  -3 -33 0 -3 -12 -6 -39 0 0 0 ...
 $ AS2        : int  -12 -3 -18 -15 0 0 -3 -5 -20 -6 ...
 $ XS1        : num  -3 NA NA NA NA NA NA 0 0 NA ...
 $ XS2        : num  -12 NA NA NA NA NA NA 0 -15 NA ...
 $ SNP_ABS_POS: chr  "22371329,22371329,22371356,22371356,22371437" "12477460,12477500,12477524,12477707,12477719" "8323582,8323583,8323588,8323750,8323759,8323791,8323868,8323878" "8323582,8323583,8323588,8323750,8323759,8323791,8323868,8323878" ...
 $ SNP_REL_POS: chr  "48,48,75,75,156" "19,59,83,266,278" "2,3,8,170,179,211,288,298" "2,3,8,170,179,211,288,298" ...
 $ SNP_ID     : chr  ".,.,.,.,." ".,.,.,.,." ".,.,.,.,.,.,.,." ".,.,.,.,.,.,.,." ...
 $ SNP_SEQ    : chr  "CCCTTCATCGCACGAATGTGTGCGT,CCCTTCATCGCACGAATGTGAGCGT,A,A,T" "T,G,ACCGGCATCCATCCATCCAT,T,C" "T,T,ACG,A,G,G,C,T" "T,T,ACG,A,G,G,C,T" ...
 $ SNP_VAR    : chr  "-3,-3,0,0,0" "0,-1,-2,-1,0" "1,1,-3,-2,-2,-2,-1,-1" "1,1,-3,-2,-2,-2,-1,-1" ...
 $ SNP_PARENT : chr  "unexpected,unexpected,expected,expected,expected" "expected,non_parental_allele,unread,non_parental_allele,expected" "expected,expected,unexpected,unread,unread,unread,non_parental_allele,non_parental_allele" "expected,expected,unexpected,unread,unread,unread,non_parental_allele,non_parental_allele" ...
 $ SNP_TYPE   : chr  "indel,indel,snp,snp,snp" "snp,snp,indel,snp,snp" "snp,indel,indel,snp,snp,snp,snp,snp" "snp,indel,indel,snp,snp,snp,snp,snp" ...
 $ SNP_SUBTYPE: chr  "del,del,ts,ts,tv" "tv,tv,del,tv,ts" "tv,del,ins,tv,tv,tv,ts,tv" "tv,del,ins,tv,tv,tv,ts,tv" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr  "BC" "chrom" "start" "end"
```

where BC=str1, chrom+start+end=str2, MAPQ1/2=c1/2, AS1/2=d1/2. This data reduces to about 20e6 rows.

The input data is sorted on chrom, start, end. Are there advantageous ways to use specific ordering?
Am I correct in thinking that using .SD requires additional memory (although memory is not really an issue atm) and is therefor not optimal?

Any help and pointers would be appreciated.

SessionInfo:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.12.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1    R.methodsS3_1.7.1 R.utils_2.8.0     R.oo_1.22.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking it into steps:

```
# Within group defined by str1 create groups based on str2 and select the largest group(s)
combinations2keep <- dt.tmp[, .N, by = .(str1, str2)
                            ][, .SD[N == max(N)], by = str1
                              ][, !"N"]
dt.tmp <- dt.tmp[combinations2keep, on = .(str1, str2)]

# In resulting group(s) select group(s) with max (c1+c2)
dt.tmp <- dt.tmp[, .SD[c1+c2 == max(c1+c2)], by = str1]

# In resulting group(s) select group(s) with max (d1+d2)
dt.tmp <- dt.tmp[, .SD[d1+d2 == max(d1+d2)], by = str1]

# In resulting group(s) select a random row
dt.tmp <- dt.tmp[, .SD[sample(.N, size = 1)], by = str1]
```

Compressing into one chain:

```
dt.tmp[dt.tmp[, .N, by = .(str1, str2)][, .SD[N == max(N)], by = str1],
       on = .(str1, str2)
       ][, .SD[c1+c2 == max(c1+c2)], by = str1
         ][, .SD[d1+d2 == max(d1+d2)], by = str1
           ][, .SD[sample(.N, size = 1)], by = str1
             ][, !"N"]
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been comparing your solution and some of mine, using the real data (10000 rows) and your code takes 66% of the time compared to my fastest version. I also tried your version with an extension `ifelse(N==1,1,sample(.N,1))` but that seems to make it slightly worse (to my surprise).
I also, finally, better understand the `dt[dt[, foo(),by=..],on=...]`. Is that the main change making your version faster you think?
Thanks again.

Comment: @Ludo One of the keys is that in each step we are reducing the number of rows so the each step should be much faster than the previous.

Comment: I made a further optimization. In about half of the cases the first grouping gives groups with a single row. By splitting the first grouping in data with a single row and the rest half of the data doesn't need to be grouped further:

Answer (score 0):

@sindri_baldur: I made a further optimization on your answer. In about half of the cases the first grouping gives groups with a single row. By splitting the first grouping in data with a single row and the rest, half of the data doesn't need to be grouped further. It saves an additional 10-20% compute time

```
dt.tmp.N <- dt.tmp[, .N, by = .(BC, chrom,start,end)
                   ][, .SD[N == max(N)], by = BC]
dt.tmp.1 <- dt.tmp[dt.tmp.N[N==1],on = .(BC, chrom,start,end)
                   ][, .SD[sample(.N,1)], by = BC][,!"N"]
dt.tmp.Ng1 <- dt.tmp[dt.tmp.N[N>1],on = .(BC, chrom,start,end) 
                     ][, .SD[MAPQ1+MAPQ2 == max(MAPQ1+MAPQ2)], by = BC
                       ][, .SD[AS1+AS2 == max(AS1+AS2)], by = BC
                         ][, .SD[sample(.N,1)], by = BC
                           ][,!"N"]
rbindlist(list(dt.tmp.1,dt.tmp.Ng1))
```

(Ps; I tried to write this as comment but it was too big)